# With Sping's cache support (for ehcache), do we still need Hibernate 2nd level cache?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I am going through and in this app, few methods are annotated with @Cacheable annotation, and those methods are cached now. Do we still need Hibernate cache as methods are already cached by spring cache API using ehcache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Cacheable will cache the result returned from method whereas the hibernate second level cache will cache the entity itself. The time when you try to load the entity it will hit the database if not found in first level cache (session scope) and second level cache is not configured. @Cacheable and configuring hibernate second level cache are two different things.

Not sure whats purpose of @Cacheable in your application but to answer your question, yes you can still consider having second level cache for hibernate.